# Rust: how to minimize patternmatching when parsing json into complex enum

Tags: rust, serde

So, let's say I am expecting a lot of different JSONs of a known format from a network stream. I define structures for them and wrap them with an enum representing all the possibilities:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct FirstPossibleResponse {
    first_field: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct SecondPossibleResponse {
    second_field: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum ResponseFromNetwork {
    FirstPossibleResponse(FirstPossibleResponse),
    SecondPossibleResponse(SecondPossibleResponse),
}
```

Then, being a *smart* folk, I want to provide myself with a short way of parsing these JSONs into my structures, so I am implementing a trait (and here is the problem):

```rust
impl From<String> for ResponseFromNetwork {
    fn from(r: String) -> Self {
        match serde_json::from_slice(&r.as_bytes()) {
            Ok(v) => ResponseFromNetwork::FirstPossibleResponse(v),
            Err(_) => match serde_json::from_slice(&r.as_bytes()) {
                Ok(v) => ResponseFromNetwork::SecondPossibleResponse(v),
                Err(_) => unimplemented!("idk"),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

...To use it later like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data_first = r#"
        {
            "first_field": "first_value"
        }"#;
    let data_second = r#"
        {
            "second_field": "first_value"
        }"#;
        
    print!("{:?}", ResponseFromNetwork::from(data_first.to_owned()));
    print!("{:?}", ResponseFromNetwork::from(data_second.to_owned()));
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e087daca46ec071d5949be6491421c8)

So, as mentioned earlier, the problem is that - this `match` tree is the only way I got parsing work, and you can imagine - the more variations of different JSONs I might possibly get over the network - the deeper and nastier the tree grows.

I want to have it in some way like ths, e.g. parse it once and then operate depending on the value:

```
use serde_json::Result;

impl From<String> for ResponseFromNetwork {
    fn from(r: String) -> Self {
        let parsed: Result<ResponseFromNetwork> = serde_json::from_slice(r.as_bytes());
        match parsed {
            Ok(v) => {
                match v {print!("And here we should match on invariants or something: {:?}", v);
                v
            }
            Err(e) => unimplemented!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really work:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'not implemented: Error("unknown variant `first_field`, expected `FirstPossibleResponse` or `SecondPossibleResponse`", line: 3, column: 25)', src/main.rs:28:23
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c8154dae9a2292f462a9ff8b004a50d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`#[serde(untagged)]`](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) is designed for precisely that use case. Just add it in front of the definition of `enum ResponseFromNetwork` and your code will work the way you want it to:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum ResponseFromNetwork {
    FirstPossibleResponse(FirstPossibleResponse),
    SecondPossibleResponse(SecondPossibleResponse),
}

impl From<String> for ResponseFromNetwork {
    fn from(r: String) -> Self {
        match serde_json::from_slice(r.as_bytes()) {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => unimplemented!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ec12eb145daa0db52cb7d11857e6d7a)

Comment: I think what the OP would like is avoid the match tree to become deeper and deeper as supporting more and more response variants. It looks to me your solution didn't meet that requirement. If the response JSON formats can be extended, adding a tag in each JSON string to distinguish different types can address the issue.  I will post my solution for reference.

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu The OP provides the code without nested matches that they would like to have, even saying "I want to have it in some way like this...". However, that code results in a run-time panic. With my fix, the desired code doesn't result in panic, but in (what to me looks like) correct behavior. If that doesn't meet the requirements, I don't know what does. Changing the on-the-wire format to fix an API issue doesn't seem like an acceptable solution, but let's see what the OP will say.

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu, this answer solves my problem, but you are right: the playground version doesn't demonstrate it. Here's a bit edited version that does: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6720be52e8be75160cd3969b92bea0b6)

Would be probably nice if you edited this answer with this link?

Comment: @kek_mek Thanks for the clarification. I've now edited both the code in the answer and the playground link to include (what I hope are) the relevant parts of the solution. (An answer should stand on its own without having to access an external site.)

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks for the clarification, now I see how this answer works. It is much more ideal as it does not need to change the JSON formats.

Answer (score 1):

If the formats of the response JSON strings can be extended (maybe not if they are predefined and unchangable), adding a tag field, say "kind", in each JSON, and annotating each variant struct with `#[serde(tag = "kind")]` and the enum with `#[serde(untagged)]` can address the issue.
[[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef2dccf9e874024638213314a3cf4756)]

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "kind")]
struct FirstPossibleResponse {
    first_field: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "kind")]
struct SecondPossibleResponse {
    second_field: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "kind")]
struct ThirdPossibleResponse {
    third_field: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum ResponseFromNetwork {
    FirstPossibleResponse(FirstPossibleResponse),
    SecondPossibleResponse(SecondPossibleResponse),
    ThirdPossibleResponse(ThirdPossibleResponse),
}

impl From<String> for ResponseFromNetwork {
    fn from(r: String) -> Self {
        match serde_json::from_slice(&r.as_bytes()) {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(_) => unimplemented!("idk"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data_first = r#"
    {
        "kind":"FirstPossibleResponse",
        "first_field": "first_value"
    }"#;
    let data_second = r#"
    {
        "kind":"SecondPossibleResponse",
        "second_field": "second_value"
    }"#;
    let data_third = r#"
    {
        "kind":"ThirdPossibleResponse",
        "third_field": "third_value"
    }"#;
    println!("{:?}", ResponseFromNetwork::from(data_first.to_owned()));
    println!("{:?}", ResponseFromNetwork::from(data_second.to_owned()));
    println!("{:?}", ResponseFromNetwork::from(data_third.to_owned()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, I am not in a control of what comes from another side, so I can't tag incoming messages. Otherwise it would totally work!